# Nokogiri aborts Rails Commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, nokogiri

I am trying to start a rails server, but I keep receiving a lengthy and cryptic error message saying that I have an incompatible library version for nokogiri 1.6.8. I have looked at other similar solutions about libxml2, libxslt, and libiconv not been linked with nokogiri and I have tried the what people recommend to fix that, but I still receive the message:

```
Sams-MBP:toy-app name$ rails server
/Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle (fatal)
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/loofah-2.0.3/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `require'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/loofah-2.0.3/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `require'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:2:in `require'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:32:in `require'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:32:in `<module:TextHelper>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:29:in `<module:Helpers>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:6:in `<module:ActionView>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:18:in `require'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:18:in `<module:FormTagHelper>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:14:in `<module:Helpers>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:8:in `<module:ActionView>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `require'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:50:in `require'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:50:in `<module:Helpers>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/rails/context.rb:7:in `require'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/rails/context.rb:7:in `<module:Context>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/rails/context.rb:6:in `<module:Rails>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/rails/context.rb:5:in `<module:Sprockets>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/rails/context.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:7:in `require'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/all.rb:14:in `require'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/all.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/all.rb:12:in `each'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/all.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
from /Users/name/RubyWorkspace/toy-app/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: have you tried updating your bundle e.g. `bundle exec install` or `bundle exec update`?

Comment: I just get a usage message when running bundle exec install, and an error when running bundle exec update

Comment: Did you by chance recently upgrade your OS?

Comment: Looks like you have your gems cached in vendor. Maybe you can try deleting the `vendor/cache/nokogiri-1.6.8` directory and then `bundle install` or `bundle update nokogiri`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Gemfile.lock` in the root directory of the application. Then, remove the versions written in the `Gemfile`, just have the name of the gem there. Then, again do `bundle install`. Maybe this can help.